# Extraer VARCHAR dentro de otro VARCHAR en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Mi pregunta es muy sencilla pero requiere un poco de programación, fácil para algunos, compleja para mÍ en este momento. Tengo una tabla que me arroja como ejemplo estos resultados:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                      Datos                       |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Hector Maya Supervisión 4 Coecillo               |
| Bulmaro Vieyra Supervisión 1 Coecillo            |
| Bulmaro Vieyra Supervisión 1 Coecillo            |
| Edgar Salgado Supervisión 2 Coecillo             |
| José A Castillo Supervisión 5 Coecillo           |
| Bulmaro Vieyra Supervisión 1 Coecillo            |
| Marco Martin Ortiz H. Supervisión 3 Oriente León |
| Arturo Salazar L. Supervisión 2 Oriente León     |
| Nancy Pérez G. Supervisión 4 Oriente León        |
| Arturo Salazar L. Supervisión 2 Oriente León     |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Mi necesidad es extraer de cada una de ellas, el último string es decir `'Coecillo'`, `'Oriente León'`, `'Oriente Sur'`, etc.

He intentado extraerlo con  `CHARTINDEX`, `SUBSTRING` y `PATINDEX`, sin embargo como ustedes pueden notar, no tiene la misma extensión y ni la misma longitud. Por tal motivo se me ha complicado mucho.

Ahora bien, también tengo que comentarles que el `VARCHAR` es dinámico, por lo tanto no pueden ser fijas. Hasta ahorita mi idea es utilizar como separador el número, porque ese tal vez no cambie.

Comment: Cada columna de ese reporte equivale a una columna de tu base de datos o todo es un string completo?

Comment: El resultado que muestras, ¿es de una sola columna?

Comment: He añadido en edición la etiqueta SQL Server ya que las funciones a las que hacen referencia pertenecen a ese DBMS. No obstante, no tengo muy claro la versión. Podrían añadirlo a la pregunta o a las etiquetas? Dependiendo de la versión, podría haber una solución u otra.

Comment: Por otro lado, si todo es un string de una misma columna, lo que los "separa" es un tabulador en la realidad o se muestran tabuladas en la pregunta simplemente por formatear y que se lea mejor?

Comment: Gracias por su apoyo, el string es completo y arrojado en una sola fila.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encontré la solución, con la función `SUBSTRING`, implementando `PATINDEX` con una `REGEX` y el código quedaría así:

```
CREATE TABLE #tabla
    ([valor] varchar(48))
;

INSERT INTO #tabla
    ([valor])
VALUES
    ('Hector Maya Supervisión 4 Coecillo'),
    ('Bulmaro Vieyra Supervisión 1 Coecillo'),
    ('Bulmaro Vieyra Supervisión 1 Coecillo'),
    ('Edgar Salgado Supervisión 2 Coecillo'),
    ('José A Castillo Supervisión 5 Coecillo'),
    ('Bulmaro Vieyra Supervisión 1 Coecillo'),
    ('Marco Martin Ortiz H. Supervisión 3 Oriente León'),
    ('Arturo Salazar L. Supervisión 2 Oriente León'),
    ('Nancy Pérez G. Supervisión 4 Oriente León'),
    ('Arturo Salazar L. Supervisión 2 Oriente León')
;

select 
     valor
    ,LEFT(valor, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', valor) - 1) 
from #tabla
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
CREATE TABLE #tabla
    ([valor] varchar(48))
;

INSERT INTO #tabla
    ([valor])
VALUES
    ('Hector Maya Supervisión 4 Coecillo'),
    ('Bulmaro Vieyra Supervisión 1 Coecillo'),
    ('Bulmaro Vieyra Supervisión 1 Coecillo'),
    ('Edgar Salgado Supervisión 2 Coecillo'),
    ('José A Castillo Supervisión 5 Coecillo'),
    ('Bulmaro Vieyra Supervisión 1 Coecillo'),
    ('Marco Martin Ortiz H. Supervisión 3 Oriente León'),
    ('Arturo Salazar L. Supervisión 2 Oriente León'),
    ('Nancy Pérez G. Supervisión 4 Oriente León'),
    ('Arturo Salazar L. Supervisión 2 Oriente León')
;

select 
     valor
    ,LEFT(valor, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', valor) - 1) 
    ,SUBSTRING(valor, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', valor), 1 ) 
    ,SUBSTRING(valor, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', valor) +1 , len(valor)) 
from #tabla
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sea de ayuda, saludos.

**Siguiendo las sugerencias de los comentarios añado código:**

[ejemplo en dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c0e85f17f9d9bfbf1bfff9e6a5b9cd34)

Resultados, utilizando la página [ASCII table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/):

```
+--------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------+------------------+
|                      valor                       |          (No column name)          | (No column name) | (No column name) |
+--------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------+------------------+
| Hector Maya Supervisión 4 Coecillo               | Hector Maya Supervisión            |                4 |  Coecillo        |
| Bulmaro Vieyra Supervisión 1 Coecillo            | Bulmaro Vieyra Supervisión         |                1 |  Coecillo        |
| Bulmaro Vieyra Supervisión 1 Coecillo            | Bulmaro Vieyra Supervisión         |                1 |  Coecillo        |
| Edgar Salgado Supervisión 2 Coecillo             | Edgar Salgado Supervisión          |                2 |  Coecillo        |
| José A Castillo Supervisión 5 Coecillo           | José A Castillo Supervisión        |                5 |  Coecillo        |
| Bulmaro Vieyra Supervisión 1 Coecillo            | Bulmaro Vieyra Supervisión         |                1 |  Coecillo        |
| Marco Martin Ortiz H. Supervisión 3 Oriente León | Marco Martin Ortiz H. Supervisión  |                3 |  Oriente León    |
| Arturo Salazar L. Supervisión 2 Oriente León     | Arturo Salazar L. Supervisión      |                2 |  Oriente León    |
| Nancy Pérez G. Supervisión 4 Oriente León        | Nancy Pérez G. Supervisión         |                4 |  Oriente León    |
| Arturo Salazar L. Supervisión 2 Oriente León     | Arturo Salazar L. Supervisión      |                2 |  Oriente León    |
| Hector Maya Supervisión 4 Coecillo               | Hector Maya Supervisión            |                4 |  Coecillo        |
| Bulmaro Vieyra Supervisión 1 Coecillo            | Bulmaro Vieyra Supervisión         |                1 |  Coecillo        |
| Bulmaro Vieyra Supervisión 1 Coecillo            | Bulmaro Vieyra Supervisión         |                1 |  Coecillo        |
| Edgar Salgado Supervisión 2 Coecillo             | Edgar Salgado Supervisión          |                2 |  Coecillo        |
| José A Castillo Supervisión 5 Coecillo           | José A Castillo Supervisión        |                5 |  Coecillo        |
| Bulmaro Vieyra Supervisión 1 Coecillo            | Bulmaro Vieyra Supervisión         |                1 |  Coecillo        |
| Marco Martin Ortiz H. Supervisión 3 Oriente León | Marco Martin Ortiz H. Supervisión  |                3 |  Oriente León    |
| Arturo Salazar L. Supervisión 2 Oriente León     | Arturo Salazar L. Supervisión      |                2 |  Oriente León    |
| Nancy Pérez G. Supervisión 4 Oriente León        | Nancy Pérez G. Supervisión         |                4 |  Oriente León    |
| Arturo Salazar L. Supervisión 2 Oriente León     | Arturo Salazar L. Supervisión      |                2 |  Oriente León    |
+--------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Otro camino, excelente. Gracias. Saludos.

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Si no te molesta, en vez de postear las imágenes, puedes usar links a demos de tu código en vivo ([acá está el código de tu respuesta](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c0e85f17f9d9bfbf1bfff9e6a5b9cd34))

Comment: Además, puedes usar otros recursos para formatear resultados y pegarlos acá. Por ejemplo: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información tenia tiempo queriendo saber como hacer ese tipo de cosas.... :D

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, ya había notado ese issue, lo que se me ocurre es sacar primero esa parte, después buscar el index del primer espacio y sacar la demás información...  Ya puse mi voto, gracias :D

Answer (score 2):

Con  `PatIndex` deberias conseguir la posicion del numero :

```
PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', cadenaString)
```

y despues hacer un `substring` empezando en el indice que devuelva lo anterior:

```
SUBSTRING ( cadenaString , PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', cadenaString)+2 , len(cadenaString))
```

Dejando :

```
Hector Maya Supervisión 4 Coecillo
```

Como:

```
Coecillo
```

Comment: Excelente!!!! Gracias, es lo que necesitaba.

Comment: @Ric_hc Me alegra ser de ayuda, un saludo